# Record H264 packets over RTP

Tags: c#, directshow, h.264

I have read through several posts about H264 recording, but none of them really answer my question, so here is what I am trying to do.

A server is sending H264 encoded video packets to me, and I would like to capture and turn the packets into a video file (.mpeg or .avi)

Here is how I envision the setup: 
I need to setup UDP listener to capture the video packets, then send the packet payload to a DirecShow graph for processing.
The DirectShow graph should consist of a H264 decoder and a MPEG encoder.

Am I on the right track?

Thank you

Comment: The question is not well-formed. For starters, you need to know the protocol data is on the wire encoded in. Then you might want to avoid re-encoding. Then DirectShow is not the only option, and with DirectShow you will need third party filters since stock filters don't fully cover the task.

Comment: Hi Roman, I think the payload is encoded in H264 with 90000 samples per second. Could you tell me what other options I have? I would like to do more research on those possibilities. 
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you wanted to tell that it is H.264 over RTP - just a guess, and a hint that you do need a research on the protocol, and this would - then - reveal the options.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention the protocol. Yes, it is H264 over RTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is capture the h.264 stream and stick it into a container, I would utilize FFmpeg.  I don't know the exact command line, so this is untested but try something like...

```
ffmpeg -i - -f mp4 output.mp4
```

Then, write to it over STDIN.  It should detect your stream type after several packets, and begin writing to the MP4 file.

Comment: There are multiple video stream coming in simultaneously, and I need to record them into different files. It seems to me that I cannot recorder multiple video streams at the same time. Is that right?

Comment: @LexL Of course you can.  One process for each stream.

Comment: You mentioned that I after I setup ffmpeg, I will write the H264 payload to STDIN, then ffmpeg will pick up the payload. If I have multiple video streams with ffmpeg instances, how does ffmpeg know which payload is for it and not for other instances of ffmpeg?

Comment: @LexL Each FFmpeg process will have its own STDIN that you will write to separately.